# Do you need to use "sic" for every error, or just the first occurrence?

Tags: errors, sic

I am typing into a computer a Civil War diary.  The (unknown) author's spelling errors are actually quite consistent.

Example:   "Troutman told Doug and me to ride ahead and *riddjup* an area to make camp."  Troutman was probably from Pennsylvania and meant "read-up" the camp.  The author spells this as *riddjup* about 40 times in a 250 page diary.

Is it necessary in a transcription to use "sic." at every error, or is it sufficient to use it only at the first occurrence.

Comment: I wouldn’t use _sic_ at all there. Make a note at the beginning instead that the original spelling has been maintained. That’s part of the charm of the charm, and dotting it with _sic_’s all over the place would ruin that. (Also, did you mean _ready up_, or does _reading up a camp_ have some meaning I’m not familiar with?)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  I have heard both "read-up" and "ready-up".   I like your suggestion of making a note at the beginning that the original spelling has been maintained, and will do just that.   Thank you.

Comment: @Cascabel  No problem.   But, since you both suggest "ready up", I am wondering now if I am misreading a "j" for a "y".   The diary is in a library and I plan to examine it for other y's in this document to see if I am in error about it being a j.

Comment: @Cascabel   About 99.99% of my questions regarding English are answered by me typing in the Title - and then being offered duplicate entries by the website.   Vrit didn't come up, but it is a very interesting post.   Thanks for the link.

Comment: Ok...got it See: https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/43/messages/709.html

Comment: As it stands, this question is off-topic as it's about an *approach to writing* (but would very much be on-topic on our other site [writing.se]). However, looks to me like there's an opportunity to [edit] this into an excellent question about the mystery word *riddjup/riddyup*, and @Cascabel looks like she has the germ of an answer. Seriously, we ***love*** questions about obscure regional usages!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about *writing technique or style* rather than about the word itself. It would be on-topic on our other site [writing.se].

Answer (score 1):

Think how you'd feel reading [sic] for the hundredth time on the same word, and edit accordingly.

And, of course, if you're doing dialect, no [sic] is needed. Huck Finn has not a single [sic]. [Sic] is there to assure the reader it's not your mistake. This one's obvious.